# How to use Google Maps in Flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps

Is there anyway not to use .swc from google maps for the flex application, as the application i want to develop will be accessible on mobile also.

Answer (score 0):

The project which was free and open source Flash implementation of google maps were terminated in 2006 ( if i remember correctly ) with the "birth" of the official google maps for flash.

Regardless it is super performance and outstanding capabilities by a very reason unknown google is deprecating them now.
( terms of 3 years support anyway ).

I would suggest to move toward some really open source map provider as well.

http://openscales.org/ ( great possibilities )

http://www.mapquest.com/ ( very well maintained )

http://www.afcomponents.com/content/documentation/umap_as3/ ( paid but interesting )

Anyway for us - the mapers. There is still a hope that google will reconsider the Flash Maps API and continue it's development.